# SQL query for Java code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I found this example how to list SQL server backup dates

http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Checking%20when%20a%20database%20was%20last%20backed%20up.aspx

**SQL Query:**

```
 ;WITH CTE_Backup AS
(
SELECT  database_name,backup_start_date,type,physical_device_name
       ,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY database_name,BS.type
        ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC) AS RowNum
FROM    msdb..backupset BS
JOIN    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily BMF
ON      BS.media_set_id=BMF.media_set_id
)
SELECT      D.name
           ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,backup_start_date),'No backups') AS last_backup_time
           ,D.recovery_model_desc
           ,state_desc,
            CASE WHEN type ='D' THEN 'Full database'
            WHEN type ='I' THEN 'Differential database'
            WHEN type ='L' THEN 'Log'
            WHEN type ='F' THEN 'File or filegroup'
            WHEN type ='G' THEN 'Differential file'
            WHEN type ='P' THEN 'Partial'
            WHEN type ='Q' THEN 'Differential partial'
            ELSE 'Unknown' END AS backup_type
           ,physical_device_name
FROM        sys.databases D
LEFT JOIN   CTE_Backup CTE
ON          D.name = CTE.database_name
AND         RowNum = 1
ORDER BY    D.name,type
```

Do I need to include  `;WITH CTE_Backup AS` at the beginning of the query when I use it in Java code?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to include ;WITH CTE_Backup AS at the beginning of the query
>   when I use it in Java code?

Yes you should, otherwise use simple subquery:

```
SELECT      D.name
           ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,backup_start_date),'No backups') AS last_backup_time
           ,D.recovery_model_desc
           ,state_desc,
            CASE WHEN type ='D' THEN 'Full database'
            WHEN type ='I' THEN 'Differential database'
            WHEN type ='L' THEN 'Log'
            WHEN type ='F' THEN 'File or filegroup'
            WHEN type ='G' THEN 'Differential file'
            WHEN type ='P' THEN 'Partial'
            WHEN type ='Q' THEN 'Differential partial'
            ELSE 'Unknown' END AS backup_type
           ,physical_device_name
FROM        sys.databases D
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT  database_name,backup_start_date,type,physical_device_name
           ,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY database_name,BS.type
            ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    msdb..backupset BS
    JOIN    msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily BMF
      ON    BS.media_set_id=BMF.media_set_id
) AS CTE
   ON       D.name = CTE.database_name
  AND       RowNum = 1
ORDER BY    D.name,type;
```

[Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) is nice readable way to introduce derived tables.

Comment: Can you show me how I can extent the query? I would like to display more useful data.

Comment: @PeterPenzov If you need more details about backup please ask new question and consider asking using http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted a question here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125739/sql-queriy-for-sql-server-backups

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't need to include the ";" if that is the first statement you 
are executing. You do need to include the WITH in the CTE (Common Table Expression) as that is what identifies the statement.

In this case the CTE will generate the same query plan as the subquery solution, but sometimes you'll find the CTE is more efficient. The CTE also offers solutions a subquery cannot do (like recursive statements).